# Error al actualizar entidad EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Amig@s, el escenario es el siguiente: al momento de querer editar un registro en mi BD, estoy utilizando `context.Entry(entidad).State = EntityState.Modified;`; el problema surge que al llegar a esta línea me lanza esta excepción

> Attaching an entity of type 'MODEL' failed
>   because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
>   key value. This can happen when using the Attach() method or setting
>   the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in
>   the graph have conflicting > key values. This may be because some
>   entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Averiguando sobre la misma, ésta hace referencia a que en teoría poseo dos entidades en la memoria de mi **context** con las mismas `PK` (o es lo que entendí).

El flujo de actualización que estoy aplicando es el siguiente (a grandes rasgos):

```
public bool Save(MiEntidad entity){
    if(entity.id > 0){
        context.Entry(entidad).State = EntityState.Modified;
    } else {
        db.add(entity);
    }
    return this.context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

Probé obteniendo el registro que quiero actualizar desde mi base de datos y agregando `context.Entry(origin).State = EntityState.Detached;` pero el problema persiste.

Cabe mencionar que si la entidad es una actualización *(entidad.id > 0)* realizo unas validaciones en las que asigno ID a cada entidad hija, pero al realizar esto utilizo el parámetro **entidad** por lo que no estoy usando el **context** de mi BD.

Cualquier orientación se agradecería!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente la solución encontrada fue agregar la funcionalidad de setear mi entidad con los nuevos valores y realizar un "*match*" a las propiedades de la entidad mencionada de la siguiente forma

```
public bool Save(MiEntidad entity){
    if(entity.id > 0){
        MiEntidad origin = context.MiEntidad.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == entity.id);
        context.Entry(origin).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    } else {
        db.Add(entity);
    }
    return this.context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Tal cual está tu código, se estaría creando una nueva entidad y solo estás indicando que va a ser modificada mediante `EntityState.Modified`. Lo que requieres es realizar una vinculación a una entidad existente usando el método `Attach()`:

```
public bool Save(MiEntidad entity){
    if(entity.id > 0){
        conetxt.dbSet.Attach(entidad);
    } else {
        db.add(entity);
    }
    return this.context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Probé con tu solución colega y el error persistió; finalmente tuve que implementar `context.Entry(origin).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);` para que funcionara; en la pregunta indique que estaba utilizando esta alternativa pero revisando mi código la estaba usando de forma incorrecta. Sin embargo, no conocía el método Attach, así que valoro la disposición y el abrir nuevos horizontes a mi mente =) Saludos!

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera me alegra, veo que ya lo agregaste como respuesta. Bien hecho ;)