# Como mantener consistencia de datos al agregar|actualizar un registro con EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Amigos, hace un tiempo atrás hice una **[pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201615/error-al-actualizar-entidad-ef)** muy parecida que en su momento me funciono pero ahora me trae problemas nuevamente.
Pasa que al querer agregar una entidad a mi BD, duplica las entidades hijas ligadas al padre *(Usuario -> Pais -> Region -> ...)*, mi solución bastante parche fue *setear* en `null` los hijos antes de insertar el padre; el otro escenario es que cuando edito un registro (haciendo `null` antes de actualizar), también me guarda las `FK` como nulas.

Averigue sobre la probabilidad de usar `Detached` a mi contexto, pero es una solución que si bien me da resultados en la insersión, no pasa lo mismo con la edición.

Les adjunto mi código

```
public bool Save(Usuarios entity) {
    //N entidades
    if(entity.Paises != null) entity.Paises = null;
    if(entity.Regiones != null) entity.Regiones = null;

    if(entity.idUsuario > 0){
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    } else {
        db.add(entity);
    }
    return this.context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

y los Modelos

**Usuarios**

```
public partial class Usuarios
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Usuarios()
        {
            this.Bodegas = new HashSet<Bodegas>();
            this.ContactoEmergencias = new HashSet<ContactoEmergencias>();
            this.ExamenesUsuario = new HashSet<ExamenesUsuario>();
            this.Identidades = new HashSet<Identidades>();
            this.LicenciasMedicas = new HashSet<LicenciasMedicas>();
            this.LogStocks = new HashSet<LogStocks>();
            this.LogUsuarios = new HashSet<LogUsuarios>();
            this.Solicitudes = new HashSet<Solicitudes>();
            this.Sucesos = new HashSet<Sucesos>();
            this.UsuarioProductos = new HashSet<UsuarioProductos>();
            this.Usuarios1 = new HashSet<Usuarios>();
            this.UsuariosFaenas = new HashSet<UsuariosFaenas>();
            this.UsuariosModulo = new HashSet<UsuariosModulo>();
        }

        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Rut { get; set; }
        public string Nombres { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        public string Clave { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Activo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaCreacion { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaActualizacion { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Foto { get; set; }
        public string Observaciones { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Extranjero { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdCargo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdJefeDirecto { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdSituacionExtranjeria { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> PoseeRut { get; set; }
        public string DocumentoID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdPais { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdRegion { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdCiudad { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Externo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdEmpresaExterna { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdNivelEducacional { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdEstadoEducacional { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsMale { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdComuna { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdTipoUsuario { get; set; }
        public string ObservacionesMedicas { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Bodegas> Bodegas { get; set; }
        public virtual Cargos Cargos { get; set; }
        public virtual Ciudades Ciudades { get; set; }
        public virtual Comunas Comunas { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ContactoEmergencias> ContactoEmergencias { get; set; }
        public virtual EmpresasExternas EmpresasExternas { get; set; }
        public virtual EstadosEducacionales EstadosEducacionales { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ExamenesUsuario> ExamenesUsuario { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Identidades> Identidades { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LicenciasMedicas> LicenciasMedicas { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LogStocks> LogStocks { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LogUsuarios> LogUsuarios { get; set; }
        public virtual NivelEducacional NivelEducacional { get; set; }
        public virtual Paises Paises { get; set; }
        public virtual Regiones Regiones { get; set; }
        public virtual SituacionExtranjeria SituacionExtranjeria { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Solicitudes> Solicitudes { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Sucesos> Sucesos { get; set; }
        public virtual TipoUsuarios TipoUsuarios { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<UsuarioProductos> UsuarioProductos { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Usuarios> Usuarios1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuarios Usuarios2 { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<UsuariosFaenas> UsuariosFaenas { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<UsuariosModulo> UsuariosModulo { get; set; }
    }
```

**Paises**

```
public partial class Paises
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Paises()
        {
            this.Faenas = new HashSet<Faenas>();
            this.Regiones = new HashSet<Regiones>();
            this.Usuarios = new HashSet<Usuarios>();
        }

        public int IdPais { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Faenas> Faenas { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Regiones> Regiones { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Usuarios> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

**Regiones**

```
public partial class Regiones
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Regiones()
        {
            this.Ciudades = new HashSet<Ciudades>();
            this.Faenas = new HashSet<Faenas>();
            this.Usuarios = new HashSet<Usuarios>();
        }

        public int IdRegion { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Abreviacion { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IdPais { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Ciudades> Ciudades { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Faenas> Faenas { get; set; }
        public virtual Paises Paises { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Usuarios> Usuarios { get; set; }
    }
```

Creo que agote mi fuente de conocimientos con respecto a esto, así que cualquier ayuda lo agradecerá mi paciencia y estabilidad mental :D

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega los modelos que estás usando, cosa que podemos reproducir tu escenario de mejor manera y esto facilitará la mejor calidad de respuestas que podrías obtener :D

Comment: @fredyfx Editada!

Answer (score 0):

Algunas dudas, ¿Estas usando EFCore o EF de Net Framework?

1.- Por lo que veo (No estoy seguro) estas usando un contexto global, lo recomendable es usar instancias nuevas de contexto cada vez que se realice una operación en la base de datos ej:

```
using var ctx = new TuContexto();
var miEntidad = ctx.MiEntidad.FirstOrDefault(...lambda..);
miEntidad.Name = "Modificar nombre";
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Eso por un lado, suponiendo que estas usando NFCore.

2.- Segundo estas usando el dominio de datos, o las entidades de contexto en toda tu aplicación, esto tampoco es recomendable, y lo bueno seria separar los dominios de datos con el de negocio/mvvm etc..., y luego realizar el mapeo a las clases de datos.

3.- Como solución rápida (No recomendable y no se si funcione), sería detachar la entidad "MiEntidad" y obtener nuevamente esa entidad del contexto, modificar esa entidad solo los campos que quieras y luego llamar al SaveChanges(), (Esto es un problema porque tendrás que detachar y obtener la instancia cada vez que necesites hacer un cambio).

Slds

Comment: Uso NET Framework. Vere como implementar lo que me recomiendas en el punto 1, el punto 2 creo que no aplica porque tengo un proyecto con N capas donde cada una esta totalmente desacoplada de la otra y el punto 3 ya lo probe sin buenos resultados.

Comment: Ok, en ese caso debes tener Ojo con la propiedad AutoDetectChangesEnabled del contexto, para ver si quieres que te detecte cambios automaticamente (true) o si no forzar cambios con "context.Entry(entidad).State = EntityState.Modified;", entonces en tu caso creo que deberías ver si tienes desactivada esa propiedad.

Answer (score 0):

Una buena opcion puede ser usar el automapper.

Primero deberás obtener de BD el objeto con las mismas propiedades que te va a llegar, en tu caso y si no me equivoco segun lo que has puesto, debes hacer una select del usuario haciendole un include con la propiedad "Area.Proyecto".

Una vez tengas el objeto de BD, puedes mapear el que te llega sobre este y no debe detectarte cambio en las propiedades de tipo Objeto pero si en las propiedades del usuario que se han modificado.

Otra opción mas rustica, es que tu objeto de entrada al servicio no tenga la propiedad Area y al objeto que obtienes de BD le hagas la select sin include. Así, cuando mapees la entrada sobre el objeto de BD, solo actualizará el registro del usuario, sin verse afectados los objetos relacionados.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Ya estoy utilizando AutoMapper, y creo que lo que recomiendas no tiene que ver con el contexto ni con la BD en si, de todas formas probare

Comment: Se me paso comentarte, una vez hagas el mapeo de la entrada en el objeto de BD, sea cual sea la opción que uses, debes hacer un update o un insert con el propio objeto de BD.